# Differences in performance of HDD secure wipe commands

Tags: command-line, hard-disk, dd, macos

I am trying to secure wipe a USB connected HDD(not SSD) on macOS by overwriting it with random data.

For some reason, only `diskutil` is very fast among these commands.
Why is this?

### diskutil

```bash
diskutil secureErase 1 /dev/disk7
```

Data written/sec: **112MB** (from Activity Monitor)

### shred

```bash
sudo shred -vf -n 1 /dev/disk7
```

Data written/sec: **57.5MB** (from Activity Monitor)

### dd

```bash
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/disk7 status=progress bs=1M
```

```bash
1308622848 bytes (1309 MB, 1248 MiB) transferred 25.013s, 52 MB/s
```

Data written/sec: **56.9MB** (from Activity Monitor)

---

(My Stackoverflow account has just been created, so I can't vote for answers yet)

Comment: Is it faster if you use the raw device entry (i.e. `/dev/rdisk7` instead of `/dev/disk7`)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Wow! Excellent. For `/dev/rdisk7` the write speed of `dd` is now the same as `diskutil`. Thanks a lot!